# Why libav-tools packet not contains avserver on Debian 8

Tags: debian, avconv

Why `libav-tools` packet not contains `avserver` on Debian 8?

I installed `libav-tools` using this command:

```
apt-get install libav-tools
```

`avconv` is avaliable after installation process, but `avserver` not. How can I install `avserver` on Debian 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obsolete and not supported upstream, due to a large number of problems reported. You might need to compile it, or try the version from wheezy-backports.

To check the state of packages, the following links are useful:

https://packages.debian.org

https://www.debian.org/Bugs/

Comment: The version from wheezy-backports might or might not work for you, you might have to extract the binary and the  corresponding /etc/ conf file manually from the deb file to keep it simple.